# Evaporation of isopropyl alcohol below its boiling point

Tags: physical-chemistry, alcohols

> Would total evaporation of isopropanol (isopropyl alcohol) at room temperature leave residue? And, why it is able to evaporate although it does not reach its boiling point?

Comment: Why does water evaporate below the boiling point?

Answer (score 6):

Residue left behind is not the alcohol but impurities dissolved in or mixed with the alcohol so pure isopropyl will not leave residue.

The reason it is able to evaporate below its boiling point is the same reason that all other liquids can evaporate below their boiling points. A liquid such as isopropyl alcohol will have a certain property called vapor pressure. Since the molecules are mostly free to move around, some move faster than others and are able to escape the fluid's surface. This will continue to happen until either the partial pressure of isopropyl alcohol in the surrounding area is equal to the alcohol's vapor pressure or there is no longer any more alcohol to evaporate. This pressure reaches this equilibrium because at the vapor pressure, there are just as many molecules of alcohol colliding with and joining the liquid alcohol as there are leaving it.

The boiling point need not necessarily be reached for all of a liquid to evaporate. Instead what the boiling point means is that once at that temperature, any more energy will go to evaporating more molecules faster rather than increasing the temperature.

So to summarize, liquids will evaporate until there is either no more or until the vapor pressure is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Pure isopropyl alcohol would normally evaporate completely at room temperature in our standard atmosphere. If there is a residue, it is due to dissolved or suspended impurities, including anything it may have dissolved from the surface that it is evaporating on. Like other volatile liquids, it evaporates because the molecules have enough kinetic energy at room temperature to overcome the forces (attractions) that otherwise hold the molecules in liquid form. In addition to their own kinetic energy, additional energy will come from air molecules impacting the molecules of alcohol on the surface. Room temperature or any temperature measures the *average* kinetic energy of the molecules. Some of the molecules have a high enough energy to create a vapor pressure at room temperature.

Answer (score 0):

One additional source of temporary "residue" on a surface after the evaporation of a volatile liquid can be condensed water droplets. Water will condense out of humid air onto some surfaces which lose heat to the volatile liquid as it evaporates. In time this too will evaporate as heat enters the surface from the surroundings. I believe the vapour pressure of the liquid must be greater than that of water (under the conditions of the experiment) for this to happen.